# PhantomJS 2.0.0 - Select: Invalid argument error

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

The script below contains some URLs in "links" array. The function `gatherLinks()` is used to gather more URLs from sitemap.xml of the URLs in "links" array. Once the "links" array has enough URLs (decided by variable "limit"), function `request()` is called for each URL in "links" array to send a request to the server and fetch the response. Time taken for each response is reported. Total time taken by the program is reported when the program ends.

I wrote a PhantomJS program (source below) to send some requests and calculate the time taken (in order to compare the performance of 2.0.0 and 1.9.8). I get links using sitemap.xml file of the sites I hardcode in "links" array.

When run using PhantomJS 2.0.0, after some 65 requests the program (method `page.open()` of request function) starts outputting the following:

```
select: Invalid argument
select: Invalid argument
select: Invalid argument
select: Invalid argument
select: Invalid argument
.
.
.
.
```

When run using PhantomJS 1.9.8, it crashes after about 200 requests with the following error.

> "PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the crash reporting guide at https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Crash-Reporting and file a bug report at https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/new with the crash dump file attached: /tmp/2A011800-3367-4B4A-A945-3B532B4D9B0F.dmp"

I tried to send the crash report but their guide is not very useful for me.

It's not the urls that I use, I have tried using other urls but same results.

Is there something wrong with my program? I am using OSX.

```
var system = require('system');
var fs = require('fs');
var links = [];

links = [
    "http://somesite.com",
    "http://someothersite.com",
       . 
       .
       .
 ];

var index = 0, fail = 0, limit = 300;
finalTime = Date.now();

var gatherLinks = function(link){
  var page = require('webpage').create();
  link = link + "/sitemap.xml";
  console.log("Fetching links from " + link);

  page.open(link, function(status){
    if(status != "success"){
      console.log("Sitemap Request FAILED, status: " + status);
      fail++;
      return;
    }

    var content = page.content;
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(content, 'text/xml');
    var loc = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('loc');

    for(var i = 0; i < loc.length; i++){
      if(links.length < limit){
        links[links.length] = loc[i].textContent;
      } else{
        console.log(links.length + " Links prepared. Starting requests.\n");
        index = 0;
        request();
        return;
      }
    }

    if(index >= links.length){
      index = 0;
      console.log(links.length + " Links prepared\n\n");
      request();
    }

    gatherLinks(links[index++]);
  });
};

var request = function(){
  t = Date.now();
  var page = require('webpage').create();
  page.open(links[index], function(status) {
    console.log('Loading link #' + (index + 1) + ': ' + links[index]);
    console.log("Time taken: " + (Date.now() - t) + " msecs");

    if(status != "success"){
      console.log("Request FAILED, status: " + status);
      fail++;
    }
    if(index >= links.length-1){
      console.log("\n\nAll links done, final time taken: " + (Date.now() - finalTime) + " msecs");
      console.log("Requests sent: " + links.length + ", Failures: " + fail);
      console.log("Success ratio: " + ((links.length - fail)/links.length)*100 + "%");
      phantom.exit();
    }

    index++;
    request();
  });
}

gatherLinks(links[0]);
```

After playing around with the program, I couldn't find any particular pattern to the problems I mention below. For 2.0.0, I could only once succeed in sending 300 requests without an error. I have tried all different combinations of URLs, program usually fails between request 50-80. I maintain a log of urls that failed, all of them run fine when I send a single request using another PhantomJS program. For 1.9.8, it's much more stable and the crash I mention below is not very frequent. But again, I couldn't find any pattern to the crashing, it still crashes once in a while.

Comment: I have now added the description of the script. Kindly see EDIT 2 :) @ArtjomB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of problems with your code. The main one is probably that you're creating a new page for *every single request* and *never close it afterwards*. I think you're running out of memory.

I don't see a reason to create a new page for every request, so you can easily reuse a single page for all requests. Simply move the line `var page = require('webpage').create();` to the global scope out of `gatherLinks()` and `request()`. If you don't want to do that, then you can call `page.close()` after you're done with it, but keep the asynchronous nature of PhantomJS in mind.

If the reason to use multiple page objects was to prevent cache re-use for later requests, then I have to tell you that this doesn't solve that problem. `page` objects in a single PhantomJS process can be regarded as tabs or windows and they share cookies and cache. If you want to isolate every request, then you will need to run every request in its own process for example through the use of the [Child Process Module](http://phantomjs.org/api/child_process/).

---

There is another problem with your code. You probably wanted to write the following in `gatherLinks()`:

```
if(index >= links.length){
  index = 0;
  console.log(links.length + " Links prepared\n\n");
  request();
  return; // ##### THIS #####
}

gatherLinks(links[index++]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is my first time using JS so I took for granted that the instances will be garbage collected. Closing the page instance explicitly for each request did the trick but using one global page instance still fails for some reason. Maybe I'm missing something. But thanks a lot anyway :)